# ALTER USER not working to change root password

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

My MySQL version is 5.7.19, when checking users data on it

```
SELECT User, Host, HEX(authentication_string) FROM mysql.user;
```

I found out that "root" dont' have password, but I know it has password.

Now I tried to assign password on it using

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'this is my password xxxxxxx';
```

It turns out this command not working. But this command is working

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('this is my password xxxxxxx') WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
```

Now I tried to change the password again using

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'this is my password xxxxxxx';
```

But instead of changing my password, it causing my password (HEX) to empty again.

Is there's something wrong with my MySQL?

I tried to create new user, assign password using `ALTER USER`, and it works!

Why this `ALTER USER` not working on "root"?

Using different VPS, `ALTER USER` works fine to change "root" password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, it seems there's a bug. This problem happened because I used copy paste when setting my password upon installing MySQL. After I uninstalled and re-instal again, now with password entered manually, this problem is gone.

Additional info about this problem, even when the password "successfully" set up using

`UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('this is my password xxxxxxx') WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';`

and I can see that there's a password there using

`SELECT User, Host, HEX(authentication_string) FROM mysql.user;`

I still able to login without password using `mysql -u root`

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but you should check the `plugin` column in your `user`-table; by default, for `root` it is not `mysql_native_password` (which would use the password).